# How to convert a vector of parent pointers to another in c++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, multiple-inheritance

How to convert two parent pointers in c++?
This is the code.

```
// base class
class B {
    public:
       virtual ~B() {};
    // other code
};
class A {
    public:
       virtual ~A() {};
    // other code
};

// child class
class C1 : public A, B {
    public:
       virtual ~C1() {};    
    // other code
};
class C2 : public A, B {
    public:
       virtual ~C2() {};
    // other code
};
// ...other C class
```

There is a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>>` which items point to instance `C1` or `C2` ...`Cn`.
Does anyone know how to convert the vector to a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<B>>`?

Comment: It looks like you could use a [static_pointer_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast) to convert each individual `shared_ptr`.

Comment: I have no idea about the real type of C. It can be C1, C2,...Cn.

Comment: do all classes that inherit from `A` also inherit from `B`? Needing a cast is often a sign for not optimal design. If the `C` classes would inherit from `AB` which in turn inherits from `A` and `B` then no cast would be needed

Comment: @NathanPierson It won't work, one needs a dynamic cast here.

Comment: I missed that this is casting across the inheritance hierarchy and thought you were casting from `Ci` up to `B`, not from `A` to `B`. Yeah, dynamic cast needed here.

Comment: If I use ```typeid()``` to get the real type of Ci, and do the dynamic_cast. It would have a lot of ```if... else```.

Comment: Not all, just the classes related in this case. @463035818_is_not_a_number The role of A and B are different. B is a new class. It would have to do a lot of weird things  if B inherits from A. And It can't be the member of C for some reason.

Comment: I didnt suggest to make `B` inherit from `A`, but rather to introduce a new class called `AB` that inherits from `A` and `B`. If you have a vector of `shared_ptr<A>` and you know for sure that they all also inherit from `B` then imho it would be better to have that also being reflcated in their type. If you had a vector of `shared_ptr<AB>` there would be no need to cast

Comment: Thank you.@463035818_is_not_a_number A and B are template classes, and have several types. My first choice was adding a new class AB, but I get a lot of compile error, and still don't know the cause. Maybe I should try it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has typos. Missing `public` in inheritance of `B` when defining `C<x>` breaks stuff.

After this is fixed sidecast does the job as it should:

[dynamic_cast conversion - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast#Explanation)

> b) Otherwise, if expression points/refers to a public base of the most derived object, and, simultaneously, the most derived object has an unambiguous public base class of type `Derived`, the result of the cast points/refers to that `Derived` (This is known as a "sidecast".)

```cpp
// base class
class B {
public:
    virtual ~B() { }
};
class A {
public:
    virtual ~A() { }
};

class C1 : public A, public B {
public:
    virtual ~C1() { }
};

class C2 : public A, public B {
public:
    virtual ~C2() { }
};


TEST(SideCast, sigleItemCast)
{
    C2 x;
    A* a = &x;
    auto b = dynamic_cast<B*>(a);
    ASSERT_THAT(b, testing::NotNull());
}

TEST(SideCast, sideCastOfVectorContent)
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> v { std::make_shared<C1>(), std::make_shared<C2>() };
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<B>> x;
    std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(x), 
        [](auto p) { return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<B>(p); });

    ASSERT_THAT(x, testing::Each(testing::NotNull()));
}
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cP919Pdfr)